# Casting error oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have tried both[CAST & TO_NUMBER] method but non of worked to cast values that is returned from another procedure.

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(SUBSTR(DETAIL_LOB, 2300, 4), 2000) 
  INTO RES 
FROM lONG_TO_CLOB_TEMP_TABLE;`
```

RES VALUE IS 40 returned by above query.

RES datatype is varchar2.

Now I want to convert that RES value into number so that I can do some arithmetic operation with this.

like => 100/RES

Not working code =>

```
V_TEMP := CAST(RES AS NUMBER)
V_TEMP := TO_NUMBER(RES)
```

Error Message => "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error"

Comment: unrelated... can't u use only `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` ?

Comment: that that was copy paste mistake I have updated.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I am searching for a particular value from the DETAIL column  that's  why using the SUBSTR also.

Comment: Are you certain that the numeric error is on the cast and not the actual division operation you're performing in your code?

Comment: It is highly likely then that you have other characters  apart from "40" that is getting fetched, a newline maybe .. OR your `V_TEMP`  variable is of shorter length.

Comment: @abhi now I am not performing any division operation  just trying to cast after success I will do.

Comment: @KaushikNayak seems you are right. Can you help me how to remove that new line.

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407135/oracle-regexp-to-replace-n-r-and-t-with-space

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely special character involve in (space or line break)

Try

```
V_TEM := To_number(regexp_replace(trim(RES), '(^[[:space:]]+)|([[:space:]]+$)',null))
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a line break causing the problem.

Solved with:-

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name, CHR(10)), CHR(13)), CHR(9));
```

--Special thanks to @KaushikNayak

Answer (score -1):

In order to remove a newline character using PL/SQL, use the following:

```
declare charwithnewline VARCHAR2(10) := CONCAT('190', CHR(13));
begin
dbms_output.put_line('+++++++++++++++++++++++++');
dbms_output.put_line(charwithnewline);
dbms_output.put_line('+++++++++++++++++++++++++');
dbms_output.put_line(REPLACE(charwithnewline,CHR(13),''));
dbms_output.put_line('+++++++++++++++++++++++++');
end;
```

Note: The newline character could be CHR(13) or CHR(10) or a combination of these two characters. The logic is the same.