# PL SQL Remove Non Ascii character but not carriage returns

Tags: plsql, non-ascii-characters, carriage-return

I'm trying to remove non-ascii characters using PL SQL. I tried to use the codes below but it also removes carriage returns which is I don't want. Please advice.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('sample string', '[^[:print:]]', '') from dual;
```

Comment: What does "not found on the keyboard" mean ? Only a-zA-Z0-9 ? There are a ton of different types of keyboard around, most of them have special characters too.

Comment: Hello, sorry. already rephrase my question. I mean characters like À È Ì Ò Ù Ỳ Ǹ Ẁ or any symbols like heart or square? Dont know if thats the right word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the regexp to (not printable OR carriage return/newline).

```
WITH t (txt) AS
(
SELECT 'Hello'||chr(13)||' World' FROM DUAL
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '[^[:print:|\x0A|\x0B|`\x0D]]', '') from t; 

REGEXP_REPLA
------------
Hello
 World
```

Nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407135/oracle-regexp-to-replace-n-r-and-t-with-space/16407316)